# Coversion of Probabilities based on time

Tags: probability

**QUESTION**  If a shooting star has an 80% chance of appearing in the   next hour, what is the chance of it appearing in the next half hour?

How does one go about finding probabilities such as this? I'm really stuck on how to start this one

Answer (score 1):

Given no other knowledge about the problem, the answer can be anything from $0$ to $0.8$.

For example, if the random process you are describing is:

- After $45$ minutes, god flips a coin with a $0.8$ probability of landing heads.
- If he landed heads, he sends a shooting star.

Then the probability of seeing a shooting star after $30$ minutes is $0$.

If the process is

- After $15$ minutes, god flips a coin with a $0.8$ probability of landing heads.
- If he landed heads, he sends a shooting star.

Then the probability is $0.8$.

Notice that for both processes (and there are many more like it, one you may want to look into is the "[Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process)"), the probability of seeing a shooting star in the next hour is $0.8$.

Comment: are we able to find this probability by assuming the intensity of the poisson process is 0.8?